# how to route all webview pages through an external server

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a custom web browser for android which is wrapped around the webView component, however, I seem to have hit a brick wall. I want to be able to achieve compression of web pages and this can be easily done server side. How can I route all pages served by the android default webView to my external server instead of directly? Any ideas?

Comment: To improve your question you should be a bit more specific and for example provide an example which page the user wants to call and what you want to happen.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The webview sends the wanted url to your server. Your server grabs the page from the url and sends it to the webview.

Comment: i want to route all pages viewed on the webView through my server,i understand i might have to extend the webview class to achieve this,but i am stuck

Comment: example user visits www.google.com, it requests the page from my server,which compresses the page and returns it.similar to what opera does,only i want to use the native webview to achieve this

Comment: You did not react on the suggestion i did.

Comment: @greenapps it is exactly what u said,but i need to route all the webview  requests to my server,how can i achieve this

Comment: Please be more specific. Give examples.